# jQuery Slider Fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm looking for a decent jQuery slider. I would like it so during the transition phase, the image fades away, hides, then fades in the next image. Like this: http://i47.tinypic.com/6gygko.gif

Right now I'm using Plus Slider but it doesn't exactly hide the image during the transition. Instead it loads the next image then, hides it while showing the second. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/EgkFq

Does anyone know of a decent slider that does what I asked above or at the very least help me with the fiddle to do what I'm suggesting? Also, the images will be dynamic and have transparent backgrounds.

Additionally I would like numeric pagination so the transition only works if you click on the number. I was told I would have to use jQuery to detect how many images, etc.

**Other than than the scrollbar issue, it's solved. http://jsfiddle.net/h7Y3F**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/EgkFq/5/

```
(function slider(){
    var slides = $("#slider > img");
    var currentIndex = 0;
    var slideCount = slides.length;
    var timePerSlide = 5000;
    var fadeDuration = 1000;

    var nextSlide = function(){
        var nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;
        if (nextIndex == slideCount)
            nextIndex = 0;

        $(slides[currentIndex ]).fadeOut(fadeDuration);
        $(slides[nextIndex ]).fadeIn(fadeDuration);

        currentIndex = nextIndex;
        setTimeout(nextSlide, timePerSlide);
    };

    setTimeout(nextSlide, timePerSlide);
})();
```

Plugin shmugin.

Here is an example of how to center the image within the "slider" http://jsfiddle.net/EgkFq/9/

```
(function slider(){
    var slides = $("#slider > img");
    var currentIndex = -1;
    var slideCount = slides.length;
    var timePerSlide = 5000;
    var fadeDuration = 1000;

    var nextSlide = function(){
        var nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;
        if (nextIndex == slideCount)
            nextIndex = 0;

        var me = $(slides[currentIndex]);
        var nxt = $(slides[nextIndex]);

        var w = nxt.width();
        var h = nxt.height();        

        me.fadeOut(fadeDuration);
        nxt.fadeIn(fadeDuration);

        nxt.css({
            "left":"50%", 
            "margin-left":w/2 * -1, 
            "top":"50%", 
            "margin-top": h/2 * -1
        });


        currentIndex = nextIndex;
        setTimeout(nextSlide, timePerSlide);
    };

    setTimeout(nextSlide, 0);
})();
```

Comment: It shouldn't be too much work to make this transition only on clicks, and otherwise expand the functionality.

Comment: Yeah, I think I've got someone to help me on that. Thanks again.

Comment: @ChristopherBurton did you remove the `position:absolute;` css style?

Comment: Yes, I removed the absolute positioning.

Comment: @ChristopherBurton that would be why. Without the absolute positioning they don't "layer" over eachother, and instead push eachother aside.

Comment: When I use absolute positioning I get scrollbars like it's in an iframe. See here: http://grab.by/fWeS

Comment: Your CSS is a mess. Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/SXGLT/2/ All I changed is the CSS. The javascript I wrote isn't the problem.

Comment: You changed it to min-width instead of max-width. Which now would result in having to rely on media queries instead of having the content flow under the sidebar naturally. Correct?

Comment: Probably. The point is, you'll need to set dimensions for the `.main` div if you want to float it.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help. I solved it using another method.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of sliders for you to choose from. Have a look at **[70+ Awesome jQuery Slider Plugins](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/08/jquery-slider.html)**. Most of them have fading effect.